# flask - preserve response header

Tags: flask, http-headers

This is how my `login` method looks like:

```
def login():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('user/login.html')
    else:
        jwt_token = "xxxx"
        resp = redirect(url_for('home.index'))
        resp.headers.set('Authorization', "JWT {}".format(jwt_token))
        return resp
```

This works fine but the `Authorization` header does not make it to `home.index` page.

How do I tell `flask` to preserve this header on every request?

------Edit---------

This works if I add Token to Cookie as `resp.set_cookie('Authorization', "JWT {}".format(json_data["access_token"]))` but I would like to keep it in the `Authorization` Header.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set `Authorization` header on all requests, you could do something like this:

```py
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    my_jwt_token = 'xxxx'
    response.headers['Authorization'] = my_jwt_token
    return response
```

More information on documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.after_request